# curl signup form data to MailChimp

Tags: html, curl, mailchimp

I've been unable to get a successful MailChimp signup when using curl to replicate a form submission. Currently receiving a 404.

```
curl --fail -X POST -H ‘Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded’ -d ‘EMAIL=TestEmail@gmail.com’ -d ’b_485e6665509b1dca9cf1bcb26_d561f45431=’ -d ‘subscribe=Subscribe’ https://twitter.us18.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=485e6665509b1dca9cf1bcb26&amp;id=d561f45431
```

Using embedded code from MailChimp I setup a bin endpoint to check what headers/payload were being delivered so I could replicate this using the above curl command.

```
Headers
X-Google-Apps-Metadata domain=gmail.com,host=*.mockable.io
Accept-Language en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
X-Appengine-Citylatlong -33.867487,151.206990
X-Cloud-Trace-Context 75c9528ee08db8469efc3c1a34d72a0a/1679801727246466213
Origin http://romantic-wool.surge.sh
X-Appengine-Default-Namespace gmail.com
Referer http://romantic-wool.surge.sh/
X-Appengine-Region nsw
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Host demo0541952.mockable.io
Cache-Control max-age=0
Content_Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content_Length 66
X-Appengine-City sydney
X-Appengine-Country AU
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests 1
Cookie __utmc=260836241; _ga=GA1.2.1607676483.1525841229; _gid=GA1.2.1814557639.1525841235; __utmz=260836241.1525927272.4.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utma=260836241.1607676483.1525841229.1525944073.1525951960.7
```

Form Data/Payload:

```
EMAIL=&b_485e6665509b1dca9cf1bcb26_d561f45431=&subscribe=Subscribe
```

All I can think of is I have my syntax wrong for the string "b_485e6665509b1dca9cf1bcb26_d561f45431"

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to work out why my original curl command wasn't working.

Bash was interpreting the ampersand within the URL argument as a separate command trying to be run, causing the URL to be malformed and incomplete. The work around this was simply to wrap the URL in quotes. In addition to this by using the -d option the request type for the command become POST by default, thus eliminating the need of the -X to specify the request type. Below is the curl command which was successfully used in this instance.

```
curl -d 'EMAIL=TestEmail@gmail.com' -d 'b2_485e6665509b1dca9cf1bcb26_d561f45431=' -d 'subscribe=Subscribe' 'https://twitter.us18.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=485e6665509b1dca9cf1bcb26&id=d561f45431'
```

The takeaway from this is to wrap all your options arguments within quotes. This ensures that bash doesn't interpret any special characters as separate commands.